# Are there any packages that actually sample randomly without including the same data?

Tags: r

I have tried `sample()`, and `srswor()/ srswr()` from the sampling package, none of these will select from my vector of `factors`, x number of unique factor levels. Just as often as not, they return two factor levels that are the same, in amongst however many random samples I ask for. Is there a package or script that can randomly select factor levels, but where no two are the same?

Comment: When you sample a vector, the function selects elements randomly. If you request more randomly picked elements than is the length of vector, you need to select `replace = TRUE`. In that case, it is expected that some elements will appear more than one time. If this is not desired, you should keep the aforementioned argument at `FALSE`. This is the case if you want to 'shuffle' your vector elements.

Comment: "Random" does **not** mean "the same value is never chosen twice.  If you want a "random shuffle," then see Roman's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `sample` from the factor levels you can simply do:

```
sample(levels(factor_variable), 10)
```

This randomly samples 10 levels from the total amount of unique levels in `factor_variable`.